# PYGAME как называется клавиша Z?

Tags: python, клавиатура, pygame

надо при нажатие на клавишу Z у шарика менялся цвет. поможете?

```
введите сюда код
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import pygame
from random import *
#настройка

pygame.init()
x= int(input("впишите x круга "))
y = int(input("впишите y круга "))
sc  = pygame.display.set_mode([800,600])
red = randint(0,255)
green = randint(0,255)
blue = randint(0,255)
rad = 50
color = (red,green,blue)
flag = True

pygame.draw.circle(sc,color,(x,y),rad)
pygame.display.update()
#цикл игры

while flag:
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
```

Comment: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html

Answer (score 0):

По идее там нужна привязка клавиш(ну или же события) Могу показать пример:keys[pygame.K_a]

Comment: ну там if event.type == pygame.:какая клавиша вот так